# Conectar Firebase ao Postman

Tags: android, firebase, postman

Há possibilidade de conectar ao firebase a ferramenta Postman ?

Preciso de algum programa que faça a conexão e depois realizasse "POST" dentro do firebase.
Preciso cadastrar vários produtos lá que contenha preço, descrição entre outros.
E para fazer isso manualmente é muito demorado.

Agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Firebase tem uma [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data?hl=pt-br) bem fácil de utilizar. Você pode pegar a URL, colocar no Postman e fazer o seu POST.

Uma forma alternativa de cadastrar vários produtos é através da [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=pt-br). Como demostrado [neste artigo](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/cli-e7188818853e), você pode colocar todos produtos num ficheiro `produtos.json` e depois usar o comando:

```
firebase database:set /produtos/ produtos.json
```

Comment: Olá, Rosário. Perfeito já estou verificando. Desconhecia esta ferramenta. Obrigado pela ajuda. Foi de grande serventia.